# defaultCloseOperation option missing in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am working in netbeans 7.0.1..

I made two jframes in it..
I made a method named close() in the in the main class:

```
 public void close(){
    WindowEvent winClosingEvent=new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
}
```

then i called this method where the new jframe is becoming visible.

Now i have to set the defaultCloseOperation as "dispose" to  to close previous jframe on the opening of new jframe in netbeans ..
But i cant find the defaultCloseOperation option in my properties..
I tried doing it through coding but it dint work.

Please help..

these are the available options in the properties of my netbeans:[image]

Comment: Your screen shows JPanel's properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"But i cant find the defaultCloseOperation option in my properties."*

Looking at the top left of your image, it shows your looking at the properties of `jPanel1`. `JPanel` *has* no `defaultCLoseOperation`. Make sure to highlight/select the `JFrame` before going to properties.